# Redirect to app URL in place of Authority URL (https://login.microsoftonline.com/) after deployment on QA sever

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am using AzureAD authentication in my existing application which is in ASP.NET MVC.

I have tested this application in localhost and it was working fine but when I have deployed this application in QA server, in place of redirecting url to Authority URL([https://login.microsoftonline.com/]) my QA server URL is concatinating with Tenant ID and client ID.
Please find below URL which is generating when request is generating for Azure AD authentication.

URL coming in browser:
[https://qa1eu.keepapp.com/XXXXXXXXX-XXXX-0000-a89c-35XXXXXXXXcXX/oauth2/v2.0/authorize]

Expected URL in Brower:
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXXX-XXXX-0000-a89c-35XXXXXXXXcXX/oauth2/v2.0/authorize]

Please find below screen shot:

[Browser Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY7pu.jpg)

Please find below code I have used in my application.

Startup.cs

```
private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
private static string aadInstance = EnsureTrailingSlash(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"]);
private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
private static string authority = aadInstance + tenantId + "/v2.0";

public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var timeoutInMinutes = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authentication.Timeout"]);
    string BaseUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"];

    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    var expireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeoutInMinutes);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        SlidingExpiration = true,
        ExpireTimeSpan = expireTimeSpan,
        CookieName = "AuthCookie",
        CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active
    });
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = authority,
        RedirectUri = BaseUri,
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
        Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
        ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false
        },
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
            SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
            {
                string name = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("preferred_username").Value;
                context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name, string.Empty));
                context.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.RedirectUri = BaseUri;
                context.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
                context.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.AllowRefresh = true;
                context.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(timeoutInMinutes));

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

web.cofig file Settings

```
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="XXXXXXXX-0000-0000-a1b1-c51dXXXXXXXX" />
<add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
<add key="ida:Domain" value="keepapp.com" />
<add key="ida:TenantId" value="XXXXXXXXX-XXXX-0000-a89c-35XXXXXXXXcXX" />
<add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://qa1eu.keepapp.com/PortalSP/signin-oidc" />
<add key="BaseURL" value="https://qa1eu.keepapp.com/PortalSP" />
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot of the Redirect URI in the Registered App.

Answer (score 0):

- I have configured the Authentication Type from the connected Services and got the default code and configuration settings.
- Iam able to get the required results with the default configuration.
- I have tried with the code which you have provided and removed the `BaseURI` from `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`.
- Iam able to get the `Authority URL`.

Below code worked for me.

***My `Web.config` file:***

```cs
  <add key="ida:ClientId" value="**********" />
  <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
  <add key="ida:Domain" value="******.onmicrosoft.com" />
  <add key="ida:TenantId" value="**********" />
  <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44352/signin-oidc" />
  <add key="BaseURL" value="https://localhost:44352/signin-oidc" />
  <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
  <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
  <add key="Authentication.Timeout" value="20"/>
```

***My `StartAuth.cs`***

```cs
 public partial class Startup
 {
     private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
     private static string aadInstance = EnsureTrailingSlash(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"]);
     private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
     private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
     private static string authority = aadInstance + tenantId + "/v2.0";

     public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
     {
         var timeoutInMinutes = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authentication.Timeout"]);
         string BaseUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"];

         app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
         var expireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeoutInMinutes);
         app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
         {
             SlidingExpiration = true,
             ExpireTimeSpan = expireTimeSpan,
             CookieName = "AuthCookie",
             CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
         });

         app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
             new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
             {
                 ClientId = clientId,
                 Authority = authority,

                 //RedirectUri = BaseUri,

                 PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                 Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                 ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,

                 Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                 {
                     SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                     {
                         string name = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("preferred_username").Value;
                         context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name, string.Empty));
                         return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                     }
                 }
             });
              
     }

     private static string EnsureTrailingSlash(string value)
     {
         if (value == null)
         {
             value = string.Empty;
         }

         if (!value.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
         {
             return value + "/";
         }

         return value;
     }
 }
```

***Output:***
[image]